# APFS how to remove unexpected "volume group" and keep data

Tags: macos, disk-utility, apfs

I unintentionally created a "Volume Group" when restoring to my boot SSD *(did something the wrong way I guess - highly confusing for me)*

I intended for the structure to be the same as the (no longer current) external copy.

I would appreciate advice on how to correct this without losing my data and system files and what exactly transpired. I couldn't choose the root/volume level when making the restore - had to choose either the "iMac191 SSD_512MB" or "iMac191 SSD_512MB - Data" and wasn't sure which one would be restored.

[image]

Comment: Looks normal to me.  Does your Mac boot correctly and with all your data visible?

Comment: I just booted from the external drive to compare the arrangement and sighed relief. It's exactly the same when booted from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the MacOS boot disk, this is normal.  The "Volume group" for the boot disk consists of the base operating system and a "data disk".  This is an intentional design to provide better protection from corruption *(accidental or otherwise)* in that most applications cannot write to the non-Data disk.

This design also generally allows for faster OS upgrades.